# About the "Selection" of the Distribute Points on Faces node

Tags: geometry-nodes

I wrote these nodes to test the functionality of Selection.

[image]

My grid has four faces. I used a mathematical operation node and wanted to control the threshold to distribute points on the specified faces.

When I set the threshold to 1, it appears as follows.

[image]

When I set the threshold to 2, I don't understand why it still looks like the points are only distributed on one face.

[image]

I don't think I understand the mechanics, but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Index is face corner index in this context.

This is in the [documentation](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/geometry_nodes/point/distribute_points_on_faces.html#inputs) ('selection' part).

Force it to face index using "evaluate on domain":

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I'll try it! By default, how do I know what data the index node is referencing?

Comment: In the doc. No general rules, I think. I've added the link to it in the answer.

Comment: Here, we can suppose this is face corners because this allows the thinner possible selection.

Comment: Thank you for your answers! Now I understand!